# When checkbox is clicked, add its value to textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to update a textbox value when a checkbox is selected, however when a checkbox is selected I get 'NaN'.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      var val = parseInt($(this).next().val());
      sum += val;
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campaignstrategy">
  <h1>Campaign Strategy</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="awareness" value="0.01">Awareness<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="directresponse" value="0.01">Direct Response<br>
</div>

<div class="targeting">
  <h1>Targeting</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="geographic" value="0.07" id="geographic_checkbox" onclick="GeographicFunction()">Geographic<br>
      <p id="geographic_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="regions,cities&towns" value="0.08" id="regions,cities&towns_checkbox" onclick="RegionsFunction()">Regions, Cities & Towns<br></li>
        <p id="regions,cities&towns_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="ringfencing" value="0.09" id="ringfencing_checkbox" onclick="RingfencingFunction()">Ring-Fencing<br></li>
        <p id="ringfencing_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input id="sum" type="text" />
```

Comment: That is a very poor ID. Can you please click edit, then the button `[<>]` snippet ditor and create a [mcve]

Comment: `document.getElementById("text1").value = this.checked ? this.value : ""`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12690213/bboooooyintheuk Is the use of jquery allowed?

Comment: @reporter yes of course

Comment: @mplungjan apologies, please see updated question

Comment: I made a snippet

Comment: Your HTML is VERY invalid AND your selector is wishful thinking. Please add the text of the hidden P (which does not have a value) as a data-attribute or access it in another way. Why is it even hidden and why do you have all that other text in there?

Comment: @mplungjan That was just for my benefit, I guess it can be removed now - but why is it even looking at the hidden P? I'm locating the value of the checkbox not the paragraph

Comment: That was not clear because the "next" I assumed you wanted to add the text of the P when the checkbox next to it was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why we are using "next()" and "each" together. Also parsing int and passing 0.01 value will always hydrates to 0. Try removing "next()" and parseFloat instead of parseInt

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var sum = 0;
      $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        sum = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        debugger;
          var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
          sum += val;
        });
        $('#sum').val(sum);
      });
    });
```

Comment: this works!! Is there a way to limit the textbox to 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it with Vanilla Javascript:

```js
const checkBox = document.querySelector("#checkbox")
const textBox = document.querySelector("#textbox")

checkBox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  textBox.value = checkBox.checked ? textBox.value = parseFloat(textBox.value) + parseFloat(checkBox.value) : textBox.value = 0
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" for="textbox" value="0.08">
```

**Edit:** Updated it after @mplungjan 's comment and your question.

Comment: thankyou! Is there a way to have the checkbox value be added to the textbox value using addition? i.e. if the textbox default value is 0 and the checkbox with value 0.08 is selected, the textbox value will become 0.08 (0+0.08)?

Comment: this would be something like ```event.target.checked ? textBox.value += checkBox.value : undefined``` inside the listener. Replace ```undefined``` with anything you'd like to happen when checkBox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

The `parseFloat()` function parses an argument (converting it to a string first if needed) and returns a floating-point number.

The `toFixed()` method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

[Learn more about toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

[Learn more about parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var sum = 0;
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
       
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campaignstrategy">
  <h1>Campaign Strategy</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="awareness" value="0.01">Awareness<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="directresponse" value="0.01">Direct Response<br>
</div>


    
  <input id="sum" type="text" />
```

Comment: this works however when a checkbox is de-selected it doesn't remove the number added to textbox?

Comment: @bboooooyintheuk I have updated my answer,  this is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to understand what you meant. You just want to sum all checked checkbox values?

```js
$(() => 
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on("click", () => 
    $('#sum').val(
      $('input[type=checkbox]:checked')   // checked boxes
        .map((i,fld) => +fld.value).get() // array of values
        .reduce((a,b) => a+b)             // summed
        .toFixed(2)                       // rounded
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campaignstrategy">
  <h1>Campaign Strategy</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="awareness" value="0.01">Awareness<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="directresponse" value="0.01">Direct Response<br>
</div>

<div class="targeting">
  <h1>Targeting</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="geographic" value="0.07" id="geographic_checkbox" ">Geographic<br>
      <p id="geographic_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="regions,cities&towns" value="0.08" id="regions,cities&towns_checkbox" ">Regions, Cities & Towns<br></li>
        <p id="regions,cities&towns_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="ringfencing" value="0.09" id="ringfencing_checkbox" ">Ring-Fencing<br></li>
        <p id="ringfencing_text" style="display:none">+£0.08 CPC</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input id="sum" type="text" />
```